# Ember Routes How To?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My problem is "simple", but I could not resolve it with Ember....

It is a Small Library App, with authors and books with those routes working fine

```
this.resource('books', function () {
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:book_id/edit'});
    this.route('show', {path: '/:book_id'});
});

this.resource('authors', function () {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:author_id/edit'});
    this.route('show', {path: '/:author_id'});
});
```

Now I want to add a route which allows me to register new books, using a link from a current author template `/authors/156`

The route must open a `books/new` template, and link the `new book` object with his `author`: ie I want to show `<h1>New book from {{author.name}}</h1>`

What route should I add to the existing ones?
How can I pass the author reference to the new book object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three ways of doing it:

1. Put it under the `books` resource and require the author as a route parameter:

   ```
   this.resource('books', function() {
       this.route('new', { path: '/new/:author_id' });
   });
   ```
2. Put the route under the `books` resource, but put the author in a [query parameter](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/query-params/) instead.

   ```
   this.resource('books', function() {
       // Declare required query parameter on controller for `new` route
       this.route('new');
   });
   ```
3. Put the route under `authors` and require the author in the URL:

   ```
   this.resource('authors', function() {
       this.route('new_book', { path: '/:author_id/new_book' });
   });
   ```

I would suggest the third option, as I think it's the cleanest. In your controller, you can create a new book fairly easily:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        createBook: function() {
            var author = this.get('model');
            var book = this.store.createRecord('book', {
                author: author,
                ...
            });

            book.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for this answer. Maybe I'm wrong but I don't like the idea of creating a `author.newbook route`. I prefer a `book.new` one. I'm trying the first option, `book/new/:author_id` but I'm stuck with another problem now: how to link the new book to the author. I think it must be done inside the `BookNewRoute`, `model: function(){return this.store.createRecord('book')}` but how?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and succeed with the second suggested method, query params.

Router:

```
this.resource('books', function () {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', {path: '/:book_id'});
};
```

Route

```
App.BooksNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        author_id: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    },
    model: function (params) {
        var newBook = this.store.createRecord('book');
        this.store.find('author', params.author_id).then(function (author) {
            newBook.set('author', author);
        });
        return newBook;
    }
});
```

and Controller

```
App.BooksNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    queryParams: ['author_id'],
    author_id: null,
    actions: {
        save: function () {
            var controller = this;
            this.get('model').save().then(function (book) {
                controller.transitionToRoute('books.show', book);
            }, function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
        },
        cancel: function () {
            this.get('model').rollback();
            this.transitionToRoute('index');
        }
    }
});
```